# Issue with symmetric matrix - appending to a list

Tags: python, arrays, append

I'm fairly new to python and I am having trouble with an array.

I'm having a problem with a symmetric matrix. Being symmetric, `X[0][6]` is the same as `X[6][0]`. I'm looking to be able to append all non-zero values in said array into a list - however I don't want to include elements on the diagonal nor duplicates of elements on one of the sides of the diagonal. For example, I only want to append `X[0][6]` but not also `X[6][0]`.

The 2D array is as follows:

```
X = [[9, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6, 0],
     [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 9, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 3],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
     [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 2],
     [0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 8]]
```

I've attempted a for loop like so:

```
non_zero_entries = []

for i in X:
    for j in i:
        if j > 0:
            non_zero_entries.append(j)
```

When I do this however, due to the nature of the symmetry of the array I get the following output which has not only the diagonal but also the duplicates within the matrix:

```
Out: [9, 1, 6, 4, 1, 9, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 8, 3, 4, 6, 9, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 8]
```

Ideally I need to be able to transform my matrix to look like this so that the diagonal and the other side of becomes 0.

```
ideal_X = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This would give the output that I require:

```
Out: [1, 6, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2]
```

How would I either transform my matrix into the one I've provided, or is there a simpler way to get my desired output with the initial matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea in writing two nested `for` loops to iterate through the elements of your matrix. The outer `for` loop iterates once through each row of the matrix, which is already correct; you just need to change the inner `for` loop so that instead of iterating over every element in the row, it only iterates through the elements on one side of the diagonal.

If you don't care which "side" of the diagonal (upper or lower) you extract the non-zero elements from, it's easiest to get them from the *lower* side of the diagonal, by doing this:

```py
for row_num in range(len(X)):
    for col_num in range(row_num):
        if X[row_num][col_num] > 0:
            non_zero_entries.append(X[row_num][col_num])
```

Note that instead of using a "for-each" loop, where the loop variable is each entire row, we use a for loop with a range, where the loop variable is a number. This has equivalent behavior (`X[row_num]` is the same as `i` in your original code), but allows us to have a variable that counts which row the loop is currently on. This number, `row_num`, is equal to the index within the row (the column number) that is the "diagonal" entry. Thus the inner `for` loop can use a range that ends at `row_num`, rather than `len(X[row_num])`, to only iterate over the entries from 0 to the "diagonal" entry.

If you specifically want the entries from the *upper* side of the diagonal, the inner `for` loop's range needs to be a little more complicated:

```py
for row_num in range(len(X)):
    for col_num in range(row_num+1, len(X[row_num])):
        if X[row_num][col_num] > 0:
            non_zero_entries.append(X[row_num][col_num])
```

In this code, `range(row_num+1, len(X[row_num]))` produces a range for the inner `for` loop that starts at the entry after the "diagonal" entry, and ends at the end of the row.

Comment: This has worked absolutely stellar! Thank you so much,